# Creating and installing Conda packages into Virtual Envs

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm working on packaging up a suite of tools that can be installed in different environments, and I've run into many problems with dependencies, which are an issue since this package will be installed in air-gapped environments.

The package will be installed via Anaconda, and I have provided the installation script. In order to create the package, I ran the following command:

```
conda metapackage toolkit_bundle 0.0.1 --dependencies r-essentials tensorflow gensim spacy r-ggplot2 r-plotly r-dplyr r-rjson r-tm r-reshape2 r-shiny r-sparklyr r-slam r-nlp r-cluster r-ggvis r-plyr r-tidyr r-zoo r-magrittr r-xtable r-htmlwidgets r-formattable r-highcharter --summary "Toolkit Bundle"
```

This produced a tar.bzip2 file that I held on to and tried to install via the conda command

```
conda install toolkit_bundle.tar.bz2
```

The command seemed to run successfully, but I was unsuccessful in importing the modules in Python. I also tried creating a virtual conda environment and importing the package.

```
conda create -n myenv toolkit_bundle-0.0.1.tar.bz2
```

There was no error, but none of the modules were able to be imported either.

Am I missing a step in this process, or is my thought process flawed?

**Update:**
It looks like my thinking was pretty flawed. A quick skim of the conda metapackage command documentation revealed the following:

```
Tool for building conda metapackages.  A metapackage is a package  with no  files,  only  metadata.  They are typically used to collect several packages together into a single package via dependencies.
```

So my initial understanding was incorrect, and the package only contains metadata. Are there any other ideas for creating packages with dependencies resolved that can be installed in an air gapped environment?

Comment: Can't you just save all the packages that might be needed to a local folder, and specify that in the `--channel` option to `conda create`? You might also need to use `--override-channels` to stop it trying to access remote repositories.

Comment: You're right about this, I could create a conda channel just place the packages in there. I was hoping to find a solution where the downloading of the dependency tree for a package was already taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at the command `conda build` for making packages, which just requires writing an appropriate `meta.yaml` file containing the dependencies, along with some other build parameters.  There is good documentation for doing so on the conda website: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages  and there is a repo of examples.

If you have a working PIP package, you can also auto-generate a conda package recipe using `conda skeleton`.

Once you have built a set of packages locally, you can use the `--use-local` option to `conda install` to install from your local repo, with no need for an internet connection (as long as the packages for all the dependencies are in your local repo).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download the packages I needed via the pypi website, and after determining the dependencies, I manually downloaded them and wrote a script to install them in the required order.